# Why won't my code work for all palindromes?

Tags: python, palindrome

I've been writing some code to take a string and check it to see if it is a palindrome or not. It seems to work on most things except for "axya" or any other non palindrome that starts and ends with the same letters. What am I doing wrong?

Code is written in python.

```
str = str.replace(' ','')
str = list(str)
var_a = 0
var_b = 0
var_c = 0

while var_a < len(str) - 1:
  var_b = str[var_a]
  if len(str) - var_a == len(str) - 1:
    var_c = str[len(str) -2]
  else:
    if len(str) - var_a < len(str) - 1:
      var_a = var_a + 1
      var_c = str[len(str) - var_a]
    else:
      var_c = str[len(str) - 1]\
  if var_b == var_c:
    return 'true'
  else:
    return 'false'
  var_a += 1
```

Comment: … what approach are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Note this part:

```
while var_a < len(str) - 1:
  # ...
  if var_b == var_c:
    return 'true'
  else:
    return 'false'
```

The function returns no matter `var_b` equals or not equals to `var_c`, so the loop only iterates once, that's why it only tests the start and end characters. You should keep looping to test the rest characters if they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

While there certainly could be a way to do this with loops, there is no need for this:

```
>>> a = "racecar"
>>> a == a[::-1]
True
>>> b = "axya"
>>> b == b[::-1]
False
>>>
```

The `[]` is an excellent operator for strings and lists.  `string[::-1]` will return the string reversed.  Check if that's the same as the string forwards, and you've got a palindrome!

To actually answer your question though :P

You're returning `'false'` before checking all your letters.

```
  if var_b == var_c:
    return 'true'
  else:
    return 'false'
```

should be more like:

```
# if these letters are different, the word is not a palindrome
if var_b != var_c:
  return 'false'
else:
  pass # keep looping
```

your program should not return true until the loop has terminated from `var_a` reaching the end, without finding any differences along the way.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, but nice!